# Jquery 'gallery' interaction results in broken image links

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, so I have just recently learned how to use jquery to switch the image source of a target div, but the resulting image loads a broken link. For a while, I wasnn't even aware of how to attempt doing this.  The fact that the script actually changes the image source of the target div is what I'm after, but I have no idea why it's returning a broken image.  One of the images in the thumbnail bar is the original image that is sourced in the main content div, but it shows up broken as well.  The code that deals with the change is something that came from a tutorial and it's nearly verbatim.

I have done a quick search for this problem and all that I'm able to find seems to be unrelated; I have not learned any PHP, so that may be a problem.

HTML:

```
    <table id="thumb_row">
    <td><div class="thumb"><img src="../../../Documents/Blacktip-Reef-Shark.jpg" /></div>     </td>
    <td><div class="thumb"><img src="../about_clicked.png"/></div></td>
    <td><div class="thumb wide_thumb"><img src="../Web_Teaser_Images/Hyp_1.jpg"></div></td>
```

```
     <div id= "content_bar"><img src="../Web_Teaser_Images/Hyp_1.jpg"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .thumb{ position: relative;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#747474;
    z-index:201;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
 }

 .thumb img{width: auto;
        height: 120px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 }

 .wide_thumb img{width: auto;
        height: 120px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px -100px;
 }

 #thumb_row {clear:both;
        margin:665px 0px 0px 0px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        background-color: none;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        float: right;
```

Jquery:

```
      $(".thumb").click(function(){
    var image = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#content_bar').fadeOut("fast");
    /*THIS IS THE LINE THAT SHOULD SWAP IMG SRC*/
    $('#content_bar').html('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
    $('#content_bar').fadeIn("fast");

    });
```

Comment: In the line that should swap the img src, you are using the variable `image`, but it doesn't have any value (it is empty). You are trying to read an attribute called '' from the thumbnail (?!). Care to give the link where you took the example from, so we can point where you went wrong?

Comment: The link is as follows:  http://designsnack.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-jquery-gallery/

Comment: Again, I'm still not familiar with the methodology behind this. I edited my post a second ago because I ommited 'rel' in the var attribute, but the change to the code doesn't fix the problem.  I also tried using the script sources the author used, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial uses the rel attribute because the event handler it uses is tied to .galImg, which is an anchor element with a rel attribute:

```
 <a href="#" rel="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/148/369304411_917e112a9d.jpg" class="galImg"><img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/148/369304411_917e112a9d_s.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
```

The divs with class .thumb that you have don't have the rel attribute, so it ends up setting the image src to undefined. The .thumb click event handler you have should instead go find the nested image's src attribute, like in the following:

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img').attr('src'); // child element src
    $('#content_bar').fadeOut("fast");
    /*THIS IS THE LINE THAT SHOULD SWAP IMG SRC*/
    $('#content_bar').html('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
    $('#content_bar').fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did wrong.  That and I think I've got a better understanding of the logic behind how to do this sort of thing.  Thanks!